# How can I filter all Trello cards that have no assignees?

Tags: trello

Is there any way to exclusively show cards that haven't been assigned to anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try searching for

```
-has:members
```

For more options on how to search see http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1145462-searching-for-cards-all-boards-

Comment: Yeah cool, this works well if you combine it with the `board:id` function. Unfortunate that it only works with the global search. Would've been better if you can use it in the board search as well.